# Disjoint set data structure in c

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, struct, disjoint-sets

I want to implement the structure on the image in C language.
But I have a problem because the 2 structures created call each other and therefore pose a problem how can I remedy it?

set data structure picture :
[Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uHWP.jpg)

liste set :

```
typedef struct liste_set
{
    set *head;
    set *tail;
} liste_set;
```

set :

```
typedef struct set set;
struct set
{
    int value;
    liste_set *liste;
    set *next;
};
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that with a circular list, pointer `tail` provides for O(1) access to tail&head - `head` is just `tail->next`.

Comment: This looks like a linked list, not a disjoint set structure

Comment: @greybeard
Wrong because ```tail->next``` is NULL
for accessing head we need to do ```tail->liste->head```
but I see what you mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is have preceeding declerations so the compiler knows what `set` is even before you actually fully declare it.

```c
// declare structs
struct liste_set;
struct set;

// typedef struct x to just x
typedef struct liste_set liste_set;
typedef struct set set;

// describe what the structs are
struct liste_set
{
    set *head;
    set *tail;
};

struct set
{
    int value;
    liste_set *liste;
    set *next;
};
```